# YIi2 FullCalendar and working with event instances from rrule post processing

Tags: javascript, yii2, fullcalendar, rrule

First StackOverflow question so my apologies for being a newbie in several areas. I have integrated a full calendar into my yii2 application and I can generate events successfully with rules. I am not databasing recurrence instances but rather feeding events in with JSON via DB calls and an RRULE string. I handle exceptions via the same string.

The event rrule I am playing with that works fine is:
DTSTART:20210430T133040\nRRULE:INTERVAL=1;COUNT=6;BYDAY=FR;FREQ=WEEKLY\nEXDATE:20210507T133040\nEXDATE:20210521T133040

My question is how do I get a parsable list or something that has all my event recurrences listed that I can work with post save once the full calendar works out the instances from the rule? My end goal is that I will have a cron that reads through my event instances and if a date matches my specific call then I fire off an email notification to the user they have an event that day or coming up or whatever.

In other words, I can get events in and displaying via rule but I can't get them out. I am coding in PHP and essentially have no javascript experience. I'm reading the documentation that says I could use .all(), but I don't know how to do that or am missing something obviously easy.

Below is the script I use to display the calendar view and is working well. The last few lines of code are just me trying to display the events in a list below the calendar so I can at least see if I can see the instances the calendar has in memory.

```html
<?php
use myapp\models\TaskStatus;

$this->title = Yii::t ( 'app','Event / Task Management | My Calendar | Active Events / Tasks');
?>
 <script src="../../vendor/bower/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<!--<link href='css/plugins/fullcalendar/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />-->

<link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.6.0/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />


<!-- rrule lib -->
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rrule@2.6.8/dist/es5/rrule.min.js'></script>

<!--<script src='js/plugins/fullcalendar/main.js'></script>-->
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.6.0/main.min.js'></script>

<!-- the rrule-to-fullcalendar connector. must go AFTER the rrule lib -->
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/rrule@5.5.0/main.global.min.js'></script>

<style>
    .fc .fc-button-primary {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: var(--fc-button-bg-color, #ff0000);
        border-color: var(--fc-button-border-color, #ff0000);
    }

    .fc .fc-button-primary:hover {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: var(--fc-button-bg-color, #000740);
        border-color: var(--fc-button-border-color, #000740);
    }

    fc-button-active
    {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: var(--fc-button-bg-color, #000740);
        border-color: var(--fc-button-border-color, #000740);
    }

    #calendar > div.fc-header-toolbar.fc-toolbar.fc-toolbar-ltr > div:nth-child(3) > div > button.fc-today-button.fc-button.fc-button-primary {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: var(--fc-button-bg-color, #ff0000);
        border-color: var(--fc-button-border-color, #ff0000);
    }

    #calendar > div.fc-header-toolbar.fc-toolbar.fc-toolbar-ltr > div:nth-child(3) > div > button.fc-dayGridMonth-button.fc-button.fc-button-primary.fc-button-active{
        color: #fff;
        background-color: var(--fc-button-bg-color, #ff0000);
        border-color: var(--fc-button-border-color, #ff0000);
    }

</style>

<?php
$jSon="[";
$coma='';

foreach($dataProvider as $row){
    //print_r($row);
    if(($row['expected_end_datetime']) < time() and $row['task_status_id'] !=TaskStatus::_COMPLETED){
        $color='#008000';
    }else if($row['task_status_id'] ==TaskStatus::_COMPLETED){
        $color='#ffffff';
    }else{
        $color='#ffffff';
    }

    if ($row['rrule']!='') {

        $jSon.=$coma."{
    'id':'".$row['id']."',
    'eventColor':'".$color."',
    'title':'".addslashes($row['task_name'])."',
    'end':'".$row['expected_end_datetime']."',
    'rrule':'".$row['rrule']."',
    'allDay':".$row['all_day'].",
    'wkst':'SU',
    'groupId':'".$row['parent_id']."',
    
    }";

    } if ($row['rrule']=='' && $row['parent_id']=='0') {
        date_default_timezone_set(Yii::$app->params['TIME_ZONE']);
        $row['expected_end_datetime'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $row['expected_end_datetime']);
        $row['expected_start_datetime'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $row['expected_start_datetime']);

        $jSon.=$coma."{
    
    'id':'".$row['id']."',
    'eventColor':'".$color."',
    'title':'".addslashes($row['task_name'])."',
    'start':'".$row['expected_start_datetime']."',
    'end':'".$row['expected_end_datetime']."',
    'allDay':".$row['all_day'].",
    'groupId':'".$row['parent_id']."',
    'url':'?r=pmt/task/subtask-view&id=".$row['id']."'
    
    }";

    }

      if ($row['rrule']=='' && $row['parent_id']!='0') {
        date_default_timezone_set(Yii::$app->params['TIME_ZONE']);
        $row['expected_end_datetime'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $row['expected_end_datetime']);
        $row['expected_start_datetime'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $row['expected_start_datetime']);

        $jSon.=$coma."{
    
    'id':'".$row['parent_id']."',
    'eventColor':'".$color."',
    'title':'".addslashes($row['task_name'])."',
    'start':'".$row['expected_start_datetime']."',
    'end':'".$row['expected_end_datetime']."',
    'allDay':".$row['all_day'].",
    'groupId':'".$row['parent_id']."',
    
    
    }";

    }


    $coma=",";
 }
$jSon.="]";
//echo $jSon;
 ?>


<script>

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
            height: 750,
            timeZone: 'America/Chicago',
            customButtons: {
                printButton: {
                    text: 'Print',
                    click: function() {
                        window.print();
                    }
                },
                addEventButton: {
                    text: '+ Task',
                    click:function(event, jsEvent, view){
                        window.location.href = '?r=pmt/task/create';
                    }
                },
                viewArchivedButton: {
                    text: 'View Archived',
                    click:function(event, jsEvent, view){
                        window.location.href = '?r=pmt/task/my-calendararchived';
                    }
                }
            },
            eventClick: function(info) {
                var eventStart = info.event.startStr;
                var eventEnd = info.event.endStr;
                var eventID = info.event.id;
                var groupID = info.event.groupId;
                window.location.assign('?r=pmt/task/subtask-view&id='+ eventID+'&start='+ eventStart+'&end='+ eventEnd+'&group='+ groupID);
                },

            initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
            eventColor: '#FF0000',
            headerToolbar: {
                left: 'addEventButton',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'viewArchivedButton,printButton,prev,next,today,dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth'
            }
        });

        calendar.addEventSource( <?=$jSon?> )
        calendar.render();

        calendar.getEvents() -> [Array];
        var list = calendar.all();
        console.log(list);


    });



</script>








<div class="panel panel-info">



    <div class="panel-body">

        <div id='calendar' >
            <script>var list = calendar.all();
                console.log(list);</script>
        </div>


    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: fullCalendar does everything client-side so you'd have to get the calculated set of events out of the calendar and then send them back to your server in order to send the emails. But that depends on the user loading the page, so it's no use for scheduled reminders. What you really need is some PHP code which can parse an rrule string. I'd imagine that exists somewhere if you Google around a bit. If not then you'd have to write your own.

Comment: Your exactly right and thats what I figured just didnt know if I was missing something. I found a yii2 plugin from rlanvin that does exactly that with rrule string parsing that skips full calendar for this entirely. Will still use fullcalendar for the calendar display and functionality. I will just build a secondary process via php. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your exactly right and thats what I figured just didnt know if I was missing something. I found a yii2 plugin from rlanvin that does exactly that with rrule string parsing that skips full calendar for this entirely. Will still use fullcalendar for the calendar display and functionality. I will just build a secondary process via php. Thanks!